# Seggregate app dependencies and project dll in docker build for an aspnet project

Tags: c#, asp.net, docker, dockerfile, docker-layer

On the docker image build samolamplee provided by Microsoft , their is a copy of all build directory in the final image. In case of a large service external dependencies size start to grew and are not so frequently updated. I am wondering if its possible to copy only thé external downloaded dependencies (liké system.text.json as exemple) and copy project generated dependency (if i have Split my solution in multiple csproj) in a second Time to benefits of docker layering système and how to do this ?

Comment: Have you checked if this actually has a significant impact on the build time?

Comment: It as impact on build, push and pull Time.

Comment: Thé project is a monolith with more than 40 mo  of dependencies. And we practice trunck base so there a lot pipeline triggered each days.

Comment: I understand that it has impact, the question is how significant it is. Is it worth the struggle of developing such approach + maintaining it  (you will need to always remember to update the base image when some dep is changed or added) compared to the  benefits gained.

Comment: Sure but i have not develop such approach actually i just Ask if someone have try to do this and if their is a straight path i will try.

Comment: Dependencies evolve but at a slower path

Comment: _"Dependencies evolve but at a slower path"_ - it is understood, but it can be a source of the problem actually - it is much easier to forget to do something which is done relatively rare.

Comment: As for approach that could be taken - I would start from migrating to the [central package management](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/central-package-management) so it would be easier to monitor changes to nuget packages. Then potentially you will need to write custom script which will copy only needed data based on the image type (i.e. publish app and copy only dependencies for base one and copy only your custom ones for the actual one) + you can consider creating an image for build which will have all nugets in local nuget cache to speed up the build part.